# Point Density and area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I would like to create circles around a point density layer that reflect the magnitude of the point density. I have created a point density estimation for a few towns. Each town varies in population, although the area does not change among them. I would like to create an "area of influence" around in town that reflects the population density. (Larger circles around higher populated towns.)

Is there a way to do this? I am using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: Are you using the Spatial Analyst tool [Point Density](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Point_Density/009z0000000v000000/)? Did you make use of the population_field parameter? I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to show, and wondering if Kernel Density or even an Interpolation rather than a point density would be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you could use the [contour tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000ts000000) from ArcGIS spatial analyst. This will create isolines based on your point density map, where you can define a threshold for a given value of your point density.